# Why same wildcards behave differently in shell and npm script?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want use `./src/**/*.js` to match every js file in `./src` folder,no matter how deep the file path is.

so I run `ls ./src/**/*.js` in the shell and the wildcards behave as I expected, js files like `./src/path1/a.js` `./src/path1/path2/b.js` and both matched.

And then I add npm script in package.json

```
{
  scripts: {
    "test": "ls ./src/**/*.js"
  }
}
```

run `npm run test`. But now only files like `./src/pah1/a.js` are matched.

I don't know why same wildcards behave differently.Can anyone tell me what is the right wildcards that I can use to match every js files in one folder.

Thank you.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117826/bash-globstar-matching

Answer (score 0):

They're just different. Shells don't expand `**`. Try `find ./src -name '*.js'`, instead.

Comment: Shells certainly can if you `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: Is that a bashism? I'm always hesitant to use shell-specific features, but that's because I use so many similar shells that I've gotten used to surviving with features common to most of them.

Comment: It's most commonly known in bash but is implemented in other shells as well. I _do agree_ that "universal POSIX-compliant" answers are generally preferable _but_ most people are probably using `bash`, as it's the default on macOS, Ubuntu, Git-bash, Min-GW, and so on, and `zsh` which is the Kali default. So a hint at this possibility is _useful_, IMHO. I should have said something other than simply "Shells".